# how to check 01 02 number

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var val= $('#num').val(); // 01
     if(isNaN(val) || val > 59 || val== ''){
   alert("error");
 }
```

In this case, has not alert error

```
       var val= $('#num').val(); // 01
       val = parseInt(val);
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking, and that isn't even a valid snippet of javascript.

Comment: ammm.. what are we talking about?

Comment: Bad question, give an example and add some English to clarify that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you code has no val in it, guessing it is a typo.

`isNaN(val)` <-- checking to see if a string is a number?

`val > 59` <-- comparing string vs a number. NOT a number vs Number

`val== ''` <-- seeing if a string is matching nothing

You want to use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for the second check. Read the linked page.

Comment: Don't forget about sending the radix with `parseInt()` i.e. `parseInt('08', 10)`. Or use `Number()`.

Comment: thank you ! convert string to number

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Define a variable name:  `var yourVariable = "01";`
- Then use typeof to find its type: `typeof(yourVariable);`

`typeof` will return `"string"`, in my example. It can also return `"number"` or `"undefined"` - very useful.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend naming variables like that - they look like global constants (and thus could be confusing). Also, `typeof` is a unary operator, not a function :)

Comment: You're right, I was trying to draw attention to it. Changed. Now, to research unary operators :)